# JVM higher allocation rate cause performance impact? how

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

GC log with -Xmx32m is below:

```
808: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 9760K->32K(10240K)], 0.0003076 secs]
819: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 9760K->32K(10240K)], 0.0003079 secs]
830: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 9760K->32K(10240K)], 0.0002968 secs



2nd Allocation rate is (9760-32)/(819-808)= 884.36K
3rd Allocation rate is (9760-32)/(830-819)= 884.36K
```

GC log with -Xmx64m is below:

```
808: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 20512K->32K(20992K)], 0.0003748 secs]
831: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 20512K->32K(20992K)], 0.0004538 secs]
855: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 20512K->32K(20992K)], 0.0003355 secs]

2nd allocation rate is (20512-32)/(831-808)=890.43K
3nd allocation rate is (20512-32)/(855-831)=853.33K
```

As per https://plumbr.io/handbook/gc-tuning-in-practice and http://stuff-gil-says.blogspot.com/2014/10/what-sort-of-allocation-rates-can.html posts, lower allocation rates are better. How?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the exact question is. The links have the subject covered. I will try to summarise:

1. Allocation rate affects the frequency of minor GC. The faster you allocate the more often you have to perform minor GC. To perform minor GC JVM has to use some CPU power to find unused objects and do other stuff GC does. This means some CPU power will be used for garbage collection instead of performing application code. Sometimes application code needs all CPU power to be able to handle the load and too frequent GC will have negative effect on the throughput. To increase the throughput one can work on reduction of allocation rate which will lead to less frequent GC and will leave more CPU for traffic handling.
2. There's also a problem related to premature promotion. High allocation rate can cause frequent minor GC and that means that some short living object may be promoted to old generation because it has survived few minor GCs. When minor GCs are very frequent then surviving few of them doesn't mean that object is long living. Promoting short living objects to old generation will lead to more frequent major GC.